# MaterializeCSS footer text disappearing

Tags: text, footer, materialize

Upon resizing my screen, I noticed that using the MaterializeCSS footer on the very bottom made the text disappear.  For example:
https://jsfiddle.net/6n6a71bz/

Specifically this part:

```
        <div class="footer-copyright">
        <div class="container">
        © 2016 Copyright OTS, Inc. All rights reserved. Created by <a href="#" class="blue-text text-lighten-4">SS</a>.  Not affiliated with OTS, made for educational purposes. 
        <div class="right"><a class="grey-text text-lighten-4" href="#!"> Terms of Use / Legal</a> | <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4" href="#">Privacy Policy</a></div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

All of the text appears on larger screens.  Also, when I try to use the line break tag it doesn't make a new line.  The same occurs when I try to make rows and columns.  Any ideas on how to make all of the text appear?

Answer (score 1):

you should try to use the materialize grid system in your footer section too

```html
<div class="footer-copyright">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                © 2016 Copyright OTS, Inc. All rights reserved. Created by <a href="#" class="blue-text text-lighten-4">SS</a>.
                Not
                affiliated with OTS, made for educational purposes.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12 right"><a class="grey-text text-lighten-4" href="#!"> Terms of Use / Legal</a> |
                <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  However, with the columns it still does not show up like how I wanted it to.  It just disappears when I resize.